# Swift 3.0 inout ArraySlice: please explain getting, passing and overloading functions dealing with this type

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

**Note:**
I am aware that there are a lot of a similar questions out there - at least in regards to "What is an `ArraySlice` and what do I do with it?". I have yet to find an answer that I either understand of explains the proper way of handling this (to those of us who do not know ever corner of Swift).

## Content

In languages like Python, making a new array from an array slice is a common function and doable, but in swift it is not so straightforward due to the `ArraySlice`.

Consider the below example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myValue = 0
    init(value:Int) {
        self.myValue = value
    }
}

var myArray = [MyStruct]()

for i in 0...10 {
    myArray.append(MyStruct(value: i))
}

var myOtherArray: [MyStruct]
myOtherArray = myArray[0...4]
```

This throws the error:

`Cannot subscript a value of type '[myStruct]' with an index of type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>'`

Some similar questions have answers relating this to type casting, and suggest:

```
if let mySlice = myArray[0...4] as? [MyStruct] {
    myOtherArray = mySlice
}
```

but this type casting will always fail.

But most answers give a more direct approach:

```
let mySlice = myArray[0...4]
myOtherArray = Array(mySlice)
```

which does not cause an error in this example.

However, if we up the complexity just a bit:

```
class MyClass {
    var array = [MyStruct]()
    
    init(length: Int) {
        for i in 0...length {
            self.array.append(MyStruct(value: i))
        }
    }
    
    init(myArray: [MyStruct]){
        self.array = myArray
    }
}

var myInstance = MyClass(length: 10)

myInstance.array[0...4]
```

`var myNewInstance = MyClass(myInstance.array[0...4])` still causes an error as expected, but now:

```
let mySlice = myInstance.array[0...4]
var myNewInstance = MyClass(mySlice)
```

does not work, with the error that there lacks the available overload.
Yes! I can overload this behavior by adding the following to `MyClass`

```
init(_ myArray: ArraySlice<MyStruct>){
    self.array = Array(myArray)
}
```

Awesome.

#### Question

Can someone please explain why making a new array from a subarray requires so much effort? An what the special overload declaration `_ :` is?

Comment: By the way, rather than iterating over a range, and repeatedly calling `append(_:)` on an `Array` (possibly including the cost of reallocation overhead), just map over the range: `let myArray = (0...10).map(myStruct.init(value:))`. It also let's you keep the immutability of `myArray` intact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you would like to create a new `Array` from an `ArraySlice`, you just pass the slide into `Array`'s initializer:

```
let sourceArray = [1, 2, 3]
let slice = sourceArray[0...1]
let array = Array(arraySlice)
```

You mention this yourself in your question. I'm not sure where the confusion is. In your particular example, you would just do this:

```
var myNewInstance = myClass(Array(myInstance.array[0...4]))
```

Now, to explain the "special overload declaration `_ :`", as you put it. `_` is simply the token used to incite that a parameter shouldn't have a keyword.

If the declaration looked like this:

```
init(myArray: ArraySlice<myStruct>)
```

it would be called like so:

```
myClass(myArray: someSlice)
```

But the `myArray` keyword adds no meaningful information, and just clutters the call site. You can remove the keyword (which is set, by default, to the parameter's name) by explicitly setting it to `_`:

```
init(_ myArray: ArraySlice<myStruct>)
```

is called like so:

```
myClass(someSlice)
```

Comment: @SumNeuron No issues here: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/587aba02aadcf805dca39a22

Comment: @SumNeuron You have to add the `myArray` keyword in order to match the signature of `init(myArray: [MyStruct])`. In this case the error message is garbage and completely unrelated, but that's the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133171/discussion-between-alexander-and-sumneuron).